# I have question regarding SQL and phpmyadmin queries

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two table in my database first is `shop_details` and second one is `shopOwner_login`

in `shop_details` table there is column named

```
ShopOwner_email
Shop_Pass
```

and same in `shopOwner_login` table there is

```
ShopOwner_Id,
ShopOwner_email,
Shop_Pass
```

Now i want to make a form in which if user enter data in shop details table like shopowner Email and its password it will store on those two table automatically goes

Can i do this if yes please help me for it i also tried foreign key i am so confused with foreign key because i am new to php and MySql please help me.

Comment: Better idea would be to keep the user and pass in ONE PLACE ONLY, probably `shopOwner_login` a that seems like a `users` table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your table should have Primary key. *Primary Key is the unique id* (could be number or string or even uuid. Ex: ShopOwner_Id) *which could be used to fetch any row in the table*. This primary key is used to establish relationships between tables.

Also for relationships there could be 3 types of major relationships between two tables.

- One to One
- One to Many or Many to One
- Many to Many

For example,

1. lets say you have two tables UserLogin and UserProfile. UserLogin contains -> id, email, password, and verified. Whereas UserProfile contains -> id name, address, mobile, dob, etc. Here Each UserLogin will have single UserProfile whereas each UserProfile will have only one UserLogin. So they have **One to One** relationship. In this case, You add the foreign key to the both tables. You will add profile_id as foreign key in UserLogin whereas login_id in UserProfile.
2. Lets say, you have two tables `Shop` and `User`. Where each `Shop` will belong to a single `User` (in your case shopowner) But a `User` can have multiple `Shops`. In this case, `Shop` and `User` have **Many to One** relationship (*or `User` and `Shop` have **One to Many** relationship*). In this case we add a foreign key of user_id (*which is primary key of `User` table*) to `Shop` table.

In your case I will suggest to only keep email and password in `shopOwner_login` table and add its foreign key to `shop_details` table. This way your data will be normalize and you will not have to make sure to maintain same data in multiple tables.

Comment: As You told i removeed id column from login table and make foreign key shopOwner_login to Shop_details but still when i submit all data only goes in shop_details table

Comment: your data will only be stored in single table. We won't save data again in multiple tables. That is the aim of normalization in sql. But when you query say shop_details table you can do a join with login table and it will also contains details from shopOwner_login table as well as shop_details table.

Comment: ok i understood it thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

So,d query need to fetch the data looks like - `SELECT a.ShopOwner_email Shop_Pass  as EmailId,a.Shop_Pass as Password FROM shop_details as a left join shopOwner_login as b on b.ShopOwner_Id = a.ShopOwner_Id`